# Unable to convert UInt64 to hexadecimal?

Tags: swift

I'm using a C function in my Swift code which produces the following result (when called in Swift):

```
let result: UInt64 = 586512487604551679
```

When I call the function in C, I get:

```
8229a7fffffffff
```

However, when I convert the Swift result to hexadecimal, I get a different value.

```
let hex = String(result, radix: 16, uppercase: false)
print(hex) // 823b5ffffffffff
```

When I print from C, I use the following print statement:

```
printf("The index is: %" PRIx64 "\n", indexed);
```

What is the `PRIx64` format and is that what's causing the discrepancy? In C, the value is of type `uint64_t`.

Comment: Checking quickly with an online calculator, it looks like the Swift value is correct.

Comment: I can't reproduce the issue. I'm getting `823b5ffffffffff` in that C code as well.

Comment: Let me investigate further.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I've no idea what PRIx64 is. I did this:

```
uint64_t t = 586512487604551679;
NSString* s = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%llx", t];
NSLog(@"%@", s); // 823b5ffffffffff
```

and

```
let t : UInt64 = 586512487604551679
let s = String(t, radix:16)
print(s) // 823b5ffffffffff
```

Comment: `PRIx64` is a macro that expands to `"llx"`, the token for encoding an "long long int" in `printf` as hexidecimal.